# "Могли открыть счет" или "Могли открывать счет"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, глаголы, аспектология

Правильно ли построено предложение:

> Дебют остался за мексиканцами, которые уже на второй минуте могли открывать счет.

Лично меня смущает слово "открывать", на мой взгляд уместнее "открыть". Прошу также обосновать ответ.

Answer (score 2):

**Дебют остался за мексиканцами, которые уже на второй минуте могли открыть счет.**

Вариант ***могли (мог) открывать*** имеет значение **способности что-то делать**, поэтому не подходит по смыслу.

Сочетание **могли открыть** обозначает  упущенную возможность для совершения действия в прошлом (могли открыть, но не открыли).

Примеры:

Этот старик **мог открывать** сейфы по звуку.

Только самым близким людям я **мог открывать** их (мысли/чувства) и ждать одобрения или сочувствия.

Comment: Но ведь во второй минуте целых 60 секунд, и у «открывать» есть значение «открыть не раз». Есть и оттенок — открывать проще, чем открыть.

Comment: Открыть счет на второй (а также на любой) минуте можно только один раз (в данной игре), открывать его несколько раз невозможно. Нужно было бы сказать: ...уже на второй минуте могли открыть счет, причем  не один раз (несколько голевых моментов на второй минуте).  Если комментатор именно это хотел сказать, то выразился неточно, а это стилистическая погрешность.

Comment: Я еще подумала, почему говорят  "могли открывать счет". Открывать - несовершенный вид глагола, действие мыслится как происходящее в данный момент. Помните: Эй вы, сонные тетери! Отворяйте  (открывайте) брату двери. Но не так-то просто открыть все замки, на это время нужно. Вот и в футболе забить мяч с одного раза не так просто, нужно несколько попыток.  Отсюда и следует несовершенный вид глагола: на второй минуте  было несколько голевых моментов (попыток), один из которых мог бы завершиться голом. Конечно, правильно - открыть счет, но хотя бы понятно, откуда это разговорное "открывать счет".

Answer (score 1):

Это стилистическая небрежность, следовало написать "**открыть счёт**".
Глагол несовершенного вида "**открывать**" (счёт) грамматически возможен в двух значениях: а) совершать действие открывания неоднократно (такой смысл в данном контексте невозможен - действие *принципиально однократно*) и б) некоторое время *совершать направленные на это действия*, завершив их *фактом открытия счёта*. Второе значение условно допустимо в настоящем времени (комментатор может увлечённо произнести: **надо открывать счёт** - сделайте для этого что-нибудь!). *Можно* и в ретроспективе сказать или написать: "**когда они открывали счёт**", имея в виду напр. подачу углового, приведшую к открытию счёта, и описывая обстоятельства этого *эпизода*. Но о простом факте открытия счёта, да ещё несостоявшемся, так сказать нельзя: он не имеет временной протяжённости.